# how to set the css for ajax success function

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm working with Asp .Net MVC3.Following is my ajax success function,

```
         success:function(data){
        $('.travTableContent').empty();
        var text3=data.data.lstunutilizedownershipentities;
        for( var item in text3)
        {    
        debugger;
        $('<tr />').html(text3[item]).appendTo('.travTableContent');            
        $('<td />').html(text3[item].CurrentOwnership).appendTo('.travTableContent');
        $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail(\'' + text3[item].CurrentOwnership + '\');">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');                                               
        }            
        }     
        });
```

i want to set the color for odd rows of(tr:odd) what jquery code i can use to do this

Comment: use `.css()` of jquery

Comment: Please post a fiddle(if you can).

Comment: why not define a class in your CSS for a table with odd rows highlighted and apply it to your table result?

Comment: are you sure this is working cause i doubt... `tr` is appended first to content with some text... and then `td` which is not valid.. `td` should always be inside `tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly, your logic would go like this.

```
 var i=0;
  for( var item in text3)
  {    
        i++;

        debugger;
        $('<tr />').html(text3[item]).appendTo('.travTableContent');            
        $('<td />').html(text3[item].CurrentOwnership).appendTo('.travTableContent');
        $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail(\'' + text3[item].CurrentOwnership + '\');">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');      

        if(i%2 == 0){
        $('<tr />').css('background', 'red');
        }                                         
  }
```

However, I doubt your code is correct. Please post a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.css()` function of jQuery and do something like this:

```
$('<tr />').html(text3[item]).css('background', 'red').appendTo('.travTableContent');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ,

```
$("#id").css("backgroundColor","yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery for this. You can define the CSS rules in your CSS file using the [`nth-child()` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):

```
.travTableContent tr:nth-child(2) { background-color: Gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use `:odd` selector..

```
 $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#fff");
```

**after the all the tr is appended to table inside the success function.**

**however i doubt your table structure is valid... since i could see your are creating `tr` appending it to content.. and then `td` adding it to content again instead of `<tr>`.... it should be added to `tr`... `<td>` should always be inside `<tr>` else it is invalid table structure.**

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create your table currectly :
TD should be appended to TR not table.

```
 $('<td />').html(text3[item].CurrentOwnership).appendTo('.travTableContent');
    $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail(\'' + text3[item].CurrentOwnership  + '\');">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent');
```

this should be as :

```
 $('<td />').html(text3[item].CurrentOwnership).appendTo('.travTableContent tr :last');
    $('<td />').html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetDetail(\'' + text3[item].CurrentOwnership + '\');">' + text3[item].cnt + '</a>').appendTo('.travTableContent tr :last');
```

like you need to appendTo `:last` TR from the table.

Once that's done, you can use following to give color to odd rows.

```
$("table tr :odd").css("background-color", "red");
```